# Class.forName() Exception in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

I am setting up `sql server jdbc driver` to my IDE, But this exception occur:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at SqlServerTests.t1.main(t1.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

My `sqljdbc_4.0` folder is in `C:\Users\Sajjad\Desktop\IntelliJ IDEA Projects\src` path.

I add this directory to library of IDE.

Comment: what is `sqljdbc_4.0` exactly ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ This folder has been produced when i unpacked the `sqljdbc_4.0.2206.100_enu` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the best place for that JAR.

I usually create a /lib folder where I put all my 3rd party JARs.

Then I configure my project to add a library that points to all the contents of that /lib folder and give that library to my module as a dependency.

It's not hard to do.  You just haven't set up your project in IntelliJ properly.

Stop putting stuff randomly on your desktop.  Proper organization matters.

I create a single folder for each IntelliJ project that I have.  Under that I usually have /src where all my .java source files go, /lib for 3rd party JARs, /resources for things like .xml configuration files, /test for JUnit test .java files, etc.

I create a library pointing to the /lib folder and make that a module dependency.

Comment: Ok, What is the path of `add library` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  The JDBC driver JAR ought to go in a new directory named /lib at the same level as /src.

Comment: I create a folder named `My lib` in desktop, and add this folder to my project, But `class not found exception` occur yet.

Comment: Sorry, this is a bad practice.  You need remedial help in how to work with Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download 'mysql connector jar' file from maven if you don't have one. Then after click file-> Project Structure -> +(sign) -> search for your download -> press OK. And you are done. Re-run your program again you'll see.